# How to add a new canvas node instead of replacing the existing node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to add new canvas nodes to the canvas node that is already in the HTML. After the first node is added as a child node, that node just keeps getting replaced with the new node instead of adding after the last node. I have tried using both append and appendChild and both are doing the same thing.

A little context, I am trying to make multiple balls that will "bounce" off when they collide either with each other or the canvas boundary.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="550" height="400" style="border: 1px dashed black"></canvas>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="increase">Increase Speed</button>
        <button id="decrease">Decrease Speed</button>
        <button id="addBall">Add a Ball</button>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const spriteObject = {
    sourceX: 0,
    sourceY: 0,
    sourceWidth: 62,
    sourceHeight: 62,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 0,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    radius: 30
};

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const increase = document.querySelector('#increase');
const decrease = document.querySelector('#decrease');
const addSprite = document.querySelector('#addBall');
const mainCanvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
let drawBall = document.createElement('canvas');


const sprites = []

addSprite.addEventListener('click', () => {
    sprites.push(Object.create(spriteObject));

    for (let i = 0; i <= sprites.length - 1; i++) {
        drawBall.setAttribute('id', i);
        drawBall.setAttribute('width', '62');
        drawBall.setAttribute('height', '62');
        canvas.append(drawBall);
        // canvas.appendChild(drawBall);
        console.log('append')

        const ballDrawingSurface = drawBall.getContext('2d');
        ballDrawingSurface.beginPath();
        ballDrawingSurface.beginPath();
        ballDrawingSurface.translate(sprites[i].x, sprites[i].y);
        ballDrawingSurface.arc(sprites[i].width, sprites[i].height, sprites[i].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ballDrawingSurface.stroke();
    }
    console.log(sprites);
})

requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= sprites.length - 1; i++) {

        increase.addEventListener('click', () => {
            sprites[i].vx = +5;
        });

        decrease.addEventListener('click', () => {
            sprites[i].vx = -5;
        });


        //change the ball's position
        if (sprites[i].x < 0) {
            sprites[i].x = 0;
            sprites[i].vx = 5;
        }
        if (sprites[i].x + sprites[i].sourceWidth > canvas.width) {
            sprites[i].x = canvas.width - sprites[i].sourceWidth;
            sprites[i].vx = -5;
        }
        //move the ball
        sprites[i].x += sprites[i].vx;
        mainCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        mainCanvas.drawImage(drawBall, sprites[i].sourceX, sprites[i].sourceY,
            sprites[i].sourceWidth, sprites[i].sourceHeight,
            sprites[i].x, sprites[i].y,
            60, 60);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a canvas cannot have child elements, so you do not need to append any children (or do any html manipulation).
I would suggest that you just keep track of your balls in an array (like sprites) and on each animation frame:

1. Calculate the new position for each ball
2. Clear the canvas
3. Draw each ball

When you want to add a ball (for example on click) you can just add a new ball by pushing it to the sprites array.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately, the same thing keeps happening. The canvas element updates instead of adds and now I noticed that the objects inside the array are also updating to be the same as the new one added.